# Setting up Id field in Elastic Search / NEST 2.0 via fluent Api

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

IdField method is deleted in NEST 2.0 / ElasticSearch.NET.  I cannot find documentation on how to do it in fluent Api now, in 2.0.  Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

[**Id inference in NEST 2.x**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/ids-inference.html) is very similar to NEST 1.x. There are essentially three ways:

- **Inferring the Id from a property named `Id` on the POCO.**

For example, imagine you have the following type that you index into Elasticsearch

```cs
class MyDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OtherName { get; set; }
}
```

NEST will look to find a property named `Id` on the POCO and use the value of this property for the id of the document

- **Using the `ElasticsearchType` attribute**

You can attribute the POCO with `ElasticsearchType` and use the `IdProperty` property to signal to NEST to use a different property for the document id. For example,

```cs
[ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = nameof(Name))]
class MyOtherDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OtherName { get; set; }
}
```

This will use the `Name` property as the document id

- **Using `ConnectionSettings`' `InferMappingFor<T>` method**

You can configure the `ConnectionSettings` to infer the id property for a given type

```cs
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
    .InferMappingFor<MyOtherDTO>(m => m
        .IdProperty(p => p.OtherName)
    );
```

This will use the `OtherName` property as the document id.

This is cached *per `ConnectionSettings` instance* so if it is unchanging, I would recommend configuring the settings at startup and using them for the lifetime of the application (you can also use `ElasticClient` as a singleton too; it's threadsafe).

With `InferMappingFor<T>` you can also set the index name and type name for a CLR type, as well as rename any properties (i.e. map a POCO property to a different property name in ES mapping) and ignore POCO properties.

The order of precedence for id inference is:

1. `InferMappingFor<T>()` `IdProperty()` on `ConnectionSettings`
2. `ElasticsearchTypeAttribute` on POCO
3. Inferring Id from a property named `Id` on the POCO